# Inner products and notations of orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $v\in\textbf{R}^3$ have norm one. If $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\textbf{R}^{3}$ and $v = a_{1}v_{1} + a_{2}v_{2} + a_{3}v_{3}$, can we have $|a_{1}| > 3$? Justify the answer.

I think the answer should be no because they are in $\textbf{R}^3$, is that right?

Comment: Right answer, wrong reason. What can the components be if the norm is 1?

Comment: (1,0,0) norm is 1

Comment: Could I have more hints?